# Missing icons and functions

Tags: 10.10, nautilus-elementary

I have installed nautilus elementary as per this **[instruction](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/ubuntu-1010-nautilus-elementary-ppa.html)**.Installation went fine. But some of icons are missing.

[image]

And there is no  Edit **→** Preferences **→** Tweaks tab. Also the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> is not working. Toolbar is not customizable. Am i missing something?. How can i make it work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the package is not installed correctly. Your best option is to go to the PPA maintainer and ask them to see if they will help you with the issue directly.

Consider that this is an experiment, and what you're doing is testing. There are bound to be problems and you should certainly report them to the elementary team:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

https://launchpad.net/nautilus-elementary

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by re-adding the ppa; then apt-get update; then apt-get upgrade. Once commands have completed run nautilus -q to restart Nautilus or log off / log on to GNOME session.

It seems that some packages Nautilus packages were not upgraded for some reason - above steps fixed for me :)